# is it possible to skip one line

Tags: c#, outlook

here i'm trying to get outlook property of the user.

if one user have some property and retrieving the same.

If another user don't have property then this code terminates.

```
result.Properties["postalcode"][0];
```

This results for some users index out of range, because this property not available.
but

```
result.Properties["displayName"][0];
```

this property available for that user.

```
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"][0];
excelSheet.Cells[i, 10].Value =result.Properties["displayName"][0];
```

is it possible to read displayname and skip postalcode property for those who don't having zip code in outlook property.

Comment: Have you considered using an `if` condition?

Comment: Why not check before getting the value if it exists? If it doesn't, don't implement your logic. See if result has a property associated with postalcode.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Outlook stuff but if `Properties["postalcode"]` returns a collection. Maybe something like `excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"]?.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use if condition for check value is exists or not.

```
if (result.Properties["postalcode"] != null && result.Properties["postalcode"].Count() > 0)
{
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"][0];
}
```

Comment: It's time consuming process. every time checks for lots of property, not only for this

Comment: You can't skip wihtout checking, for that you need if or ?. But there can be optimal solutions if you can share more info. Like your results data structure and expected results...

Comment: result data from outlook property. one user may have country or zip code property and another user may not having country property. Its difficult to check each and every user when it comes to 1000 users. one way is try catch block for each property statemenst

Comment: Use try get value then.

Comment: if returns null, then it will catch in catch block and next property won't effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use a null-conditional:

```
excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"]?[0];
```

The trick is question mark after `["postalcode"]`. It's a syntactic sugar, that replaces

```
if(result.Properties["postalcode"]!=null)
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"][0];
else
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = null;
```

**UPDATE:** If you need to return some certain value instead of a null, you need a null-coalecsing operator. E.g. if you need to insert "" instead of null it looks like

```
excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"]?[0]??"";
```

that replaces

```
if(result.Properties["postalcode"]!=null)
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"][0];
else
    excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = "";
```

There is one more case: if you have a certain value in `excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value`, want to keep it and want to use a single-liner. Than you can do such a trick

```
excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value = result.Properties["postalcode"]?[0]??excelSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value;
```

Comment: Its not working, idea is good. I'm looking this kind of stuff ternary operator

Comment: @Arya if you need a condition (e.g. if the ["postalcode"] is null then make Value zero you can do it with a null-coalescing operator — see update.

Comment: @MaxB not if null is a valid value for a Value property, e.g. if it is a string.

Comment: good one. But if property doesn't exist for the user, it will return index out of exception. That's why i used try catch block for this stuff.

Comment: @ДмитроІванов I simply fixed your code, the first piece of it, with "?". Your first piece of code just won't compile. Now, after your edits, I understand that you were trying to use "?" as in "list[0]?.ToString()", but your use of it is wrong, you can't access "[0]" the way you were trying to. Edit: At least not in my low version .Net testing program. It might be possible in later versions

Comment: @MaxB it does compile. Is is a null-conditional operator. E.g. we have an object SomeObject with a property SomeProperty. If we do var someVariable = SomeObject.SomeProperty we will get an exception if SomeObject == null, because the expression will try to get SomeProperty of a null and it has none. But if we use SomeObject?.SomeProperty it will return null if SomeObject is null without querying SomeProperty. For an array it looks like var someVariable = someArray?[0] and returns null is someArray is null.

Comment: @MaxB BTW your code wont do the job. Null-coalescent operator you use returns a value or, if value is null, the specified default value. So you line will return result.Properties["postalcode"] if result.Properties["postalcode"] is not null. And if it is null it will try to return result.Properties["postalcode"][0] which, of course will fail(result.Property["postalcode"] is null, remember?) and throw an exception.

Comment: @MaxB and yes, there's a possibility you can not use it due to a low version of C#. It was introduced in C# 6.0. You need at leas VS2015 to use it.

Comment: @ДмитроІванов You're right that my piece of code is wrong. I forgot to think what I was writing, only concentrated on syntax, it's my bad. Either way, I can't make your first piece of code work. Now seeing your last comment, I believe that's the case, I'm using C# 5, that's the sad reality. Sorry for any inconvenience I've brought to you

Comment: I've deleted the comment with the code I suggested, since it's logically wrong